# Самая быстрая функция(метод) для поиска максимума/минимума в списке/массиве

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Мне известно две функции поиска экстремумов в массиве: 1. Базовая функция `max()`; 2. `numpy.max()`. Я измерил скорость выполнения каждой из этих функций: `numpy` выигрывает у базовой функции два порядка. Но, при этом, надо учитывать время препроцессинга, то есть конвертация из базового списка в `numpy.array`, чтобы последующая экономия времени на операциях с массивом не была нивелирована временем препроцессинга.

Вопрос: есть ли еще более быстрые функции для поиска экстремумов, с учетом того, что препроцессинг тоже имеет значение. Мне достаточно накидать сюда функций/методов/структур данных. Замеры я сделаю сам. Спасибо!

Comment: Расклад тут очень сильно зависит от того, ищете ли вы много раз что-то в одних данных или только один раз. И обязательно ли, чтобы на вход приходили списки питона, вы не можете их заранее преобразовать? В общем, нужен весь пайплайн, чтобы понимать, как ускорить. И вообще хорошо бы описать, что у вас собственно в целом за задача. Может вы не там ищете ускорение вообще.

Comment: @CrazyElf Я могу данные заранее преобразовать. Мне и важно понять в чем хранить. В списках, в нампи массивах или **еще в чем-то**, что позволит еще быстрее осуществлять поиск. На данный момент мне понятно, что даже если я всего два раза буду искать max или min, то выигрыш в поиске окупит проигрыш в конвертации в нампи массив. Я поэтому и прошу информации о функциях и структурах данных, чтобы померить выполнение уже под свою задачу. Я к сожалению, всю задачу описать не могу. Будем считать, что просто ищу экстремумы и критерием является скорость поиска без учета препроцессинга.

Comment: [что нашёл](https://pythonru.com/primery/python-maksimalnyj-element-massiva#:~:text=%E2%84%961%20%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F,%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)
Нашёл сайт с ф-ями, которие перебирають списки, кортежы, массивы...

Comment: Ну в такой постановке, вы вряд ли что-то быстрее, чем `numpy` найдёте. Он написан на `C++` и максимально оптимизирован, чтобы работать с однородными массивами. Можно, конечно, всякое распараллеливание ещё попробовать, но вряд ли в этом случае имеет смысл с ним возиться. А так то можно и в `SQL` базу данные сложить и много чего придумать. Когда непонятно сколько вообще данных и какой сценарий использования, то советовать сложно.

Comment: @CrazyElf Данных миллионы элементов, десятизначные int. Я беру данные из SQL, не улавливаю чем это может помочь, в данном контексте. Селект максимума/минимума будет работать медленнее чем выполнение того же алгоритма в памяти. Я проверил, из интереса: селект максимума по той же выборке работает на порядок медленнее базового max. В любом случае, спасибо - если Вы считаете, что кроме нампи, в такой постановке задачи ничего не придумаешь, то я из этого и буду исходить. Благодарю!

Comment: Ваши массивы изменяются?

Comment: @MBo Если я правильно понимаю, о чем Вы спрашиваете, то - нет. На вход поступают все новые и новые массивы. Но каждый из этих массивов, после того как попал в алгоритм - не меняется.

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov При наличии правильных индексов в таблицах выбор минимума и максимума из таблицы должен работать быстрее всего для миллионов элементов, даже при наличии каких-то дополнительных условий в выборках. Ну, если только коннект к БД не тормозит ещё. Так что странная ситуация. Разве что вы ещё что-то такое делаете с данными, чего нельзя сделать прямо в БД. Если при выборке используется индекс, то она должна довольно быстро работать. А так то если массивы не меняются, то вообще непонятно, зачем в них повторно искать экстремумы, лучше их куда-то кешировать, будет ещё быстрее )

Comment: @CrazyElf Про индексы SQL я изучу вопрос, спасибо, возможно, что я с этими индексами упускаю что-то важное. Коннект вряд ли тормозит - и скрипт и БД на локальной машине, я запускаю несколько итераций, чтобы измерить скорость и беру среднее. Относительно того, что экстремумы проще хранить, согласен, конечно. Этот вопрос скорее приобрел уже академический интерес, нежели прикладной - есть ли что-то быстрее нампи? Проверю вариант с SQL и индексами - возможно, будет быстрее.

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov Научитесь профилировать запросы `SQL`, читать план запроса и т.д. Поначалу сложно, но зато очень полезно. Хорошо выстроенная и настроенная БД - очень полезная штука. Особенно если речь о миллионах записей. Очень много себе времени потом сэкономите на чтении данных из БД если и не в этой задаче, то в других.

Comment: Максимум ищется с той же скоростью, с которой вы можете читать данные для которых его ищете. По этой причине никто не пытается оптимизировать поиск максимума - время получения данных будет больше чем время расчёта. Тогда какой смысл оптимизировать меньшую (по времени) часть алгоритма? Ищите способ не читать все данные. Индекс в базе данных или специальная структура данных (куча, упорядоченные контейнеры, деревья отрезков). Просто ускорять расчёт максимума по набору чисел не продуктивно.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Благодарю за советы! Буду изучать специализированные структуры данных.